# Wrapping all keys in double curly in YML file with Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, yaml, sublimetext

I'd like to do a quick manipulation on a YML file that'll wrap all keys in double curly braces and strip the quotations , such as:

```
level:
  group:
    continue: "continue"
    stop: "stop"
    go: "go"
    halt: "halt"
```

becomes

```
{{level:}}
  {{group:}}
    {{continue:}} continue
    {{stop:}} stop
    {{go:}} go
    {{halt:}} halt
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this using multicursor, but so far no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expression! 
You want to do a replace (`Find->Replace...`), searching for `(\w+?:)`,  and replace with `{{\1}}`.

This should do what you expect (I'll add a little explanation when I'm back on my laptop).

- `\w` is for any alphanumeric characters, and things like `_`, so that would be your identifier
- `+?`: any number (but at least one) of said set of character, but in a non-greedy way (or it would also match the `:` I put after)
- `:` is obviously the end of your identifier
- `(...)` means you capture everything inside, and store it in `\1`

That's why the replace is: `{{\1}}`

Demo:
http://regex101.com/r/yE5pM1/1

Comment: Such beauty, I didn't realize we could use regex in Sublime. Thanks so much! And thanks for showing a man how to fish instead of simply giving him a fish :)